# Calling future / async with user defined parameter and invoking a class method

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to call a function async and return a value with a class method:

```
void A::GetReply()
{
auto fn = std::async([this](const struct mydata& msg)
    {
        oncall(msg);
    });
}
int A::onReply(const struct mydata& msg)
{
return msg.value;
}
```

I get compilation error:

```
6>: error C2672: 'std::async': no matching overloaded function found
6>: error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::future<_Invoke_traits<void,_Callable,decay<_ArgTypes>::type...>::type> std::async(_Fty &&,_ArgTypes &&...)'
6>        with
6>        [
6>            _Callable=decay<_Ty>::type
6>        ]
6>: note: With the following template arguments:
6>: note: '_Fty=A::{ctor}::<lambda_75cbb6e549dc12613fd9546c1d31aa61>'
6>: note: '_ArgTypes={}'
6>: error C2780: 'std::future<_Invoke_traits<void,_Callable,decay<_ArgTypes>::type...>::type> std::async(std::launch,_Fty &&,_ArgTypes &&...)': expects 3 arguments - 1 provided
6>        with
6>        [
6>            _Callable=decay<_Ty>::type
6>        ]
6>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\future(1821): note: see declaration of 'std::async'
```

What is correct way of implementation a function call for 'future' with launch as async and get the return value of the async function call?

Comment: I think you've gone to minimal with your example.  `std::async([this](const struct mydata& msg)
    {
        oncall(msg);
    }));` isn't syntactically correct, there is an extra `)` at the end.  Also there is no closing `}` for `GetReply`

Comment: Thanks - corrected the same was a typo mistake here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with

```
auto fn = std::async([this](const struct mydata& msg)
    {
        oncall(msg);
    });
```

is the lambda expects an argument, but you don't pass one to `async`.  You have to a pass to `async` the function you want to run asynchronously and all of its parameters.  If `msg` is a member of the class then you could change the signature to

```
auto fn = std::async([this]()
    {
        oncall(msg);
    });
```

and then `msg` is `this->msg`.

Comment: Thanks it solved the compilation error - I am new to usage to std::future - how can I invoke and pass the value of the async function call later in my code?

Comment: @Programmer So you want to set up a async function, but call it later once you know the parameters for it?

Comment: Yes and is it possible that the return value be a string or int types - I mean it can vary on a conditional return statement

Comment: @Programmer I'm not sure.  There probably is a way but I can't think how to plumb it all out right now.  As far as having a function that returns different things goes, all paths out of a function must return the same thing, or all be convertible to the same thing.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question for that.